# Swift optional multiple tests in conditional

Tags: ios, swift, conditional-statements, swift4

I want to do something like this with an optional in swift.

```
 var opt:MyOptional?

func myfunction() {
   if (opt == nil) || (opt?.x != 10 && opt?.y != 20)) {
    opt = MyOptional()
    opt.x = 10
    opt.y = 20
 }
}
```

My question is if this is a valid pattern, even though it compiles and runs. Does Swift compiler ensures condition 2 runs after condition 1 (opt!= nil)?

Comment: I think it should be && instead of ||

Comment: *even though it compiles*. Actually it does not compile.

Comment: It won't compile for one reason - **opt2?.y** - *opt2* is undefined.

Comment: Can you clarify which is the condition 1 from below 1) (opt!= nil)? 2) (opt == nil), I have your answer , but please clarify the above.

Answer (score 2):

Well `&& and ||` operators in swift are `Left Associative` which means your evaluation of conditions goes from `left hand side`.

```
(opt != nil). // result 1
```

this condition will get evaluate first and as you are using the `||` operator.

Secondaly your `(opt?.x != 10 && opt2?.y != 20)` // result 2 
will get now evaluate if your **result 1** is false otherwise it would have gone in the loop because of `||` operator

> final condition

```
 if (result 1 || result 2) {
```

**if only result 1 is true it not evaluate for result 2 due to || operator otherwise it would calculate result 2 and if result 2 is true its a success**

Comment: This isn't quite correct – it is true that `||` is left associative, but left associativity only impacts how the operator behaves when chained together, e.g `a || b || c` is evaluated as `(a || b) || c` because of left associativity. But in the case of just `a || b`, left associativity doesn't have any impact. `||` can *short circuit* because the right-hand operand is `@autoclosure`, meaning that Swift will implicitly wrap the expression in a closure, allowing the operator implementation not to evaluate it if the left operand evaluates to true. This behaviour is unrelated to associativity.

Comment: You are right @Hamish . Associativity is only when there are three or more operators.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have got a typo this code should looks like this:

```
struct MyOptional {
    var x: Int = 0
    var y: Int = 0
}
class SomeClass {
    var opt: MyOptional?

    func myFunction() {
        if let unwrappedOpt = opt,
            unwrappedOpt.x != 10 && unwrappedOpt.y != 20 {
            opt = MyOptional(x: 10, y: 20)
        }
    }
}
```

What about your question? You are right.